# Union and if with value present in other table Power BI

Tags: if-statement, union, powerbi, m

I have 3 tables.

The first one is a product table

[image: Product Table]

The second one is also a product table, but some product are also present in the first one.

[image: Second Product Table]

And finally, I have a sales table.

[image: Sales Table]

I would like to union the two product tables into a new one and if one product is in 'Sales', then add a new column with the name of the client.

This kind of results.

[image: Result]

I want to do it in Power BI, but I can't find a solution to do it in Query Editor.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I assume `ID` is the primary key across the tables.

First, you can append (i.e. union) the two `Product` table into one:

[image: append 1]

[image: append 2]

Then, remove duplicates on the `ID` column:

[image: remove duplicates]

Now, you can merge (i.e. join) the query with `Sales` table on `ID` column:

[image: merge 1]

[image: merge 2]

Expand the `Sales` table and select only the `ClientName` column:

[image: expand 1]

[image: expand 2]

And finally, replace the null value with `Unsold`:

[image: replace 1]

[image: replace 2]

(Yes, it's weird that the string `null` means `NULL` but it works this way)

Final result:

[image: result]

Full M code for your reference:

```
let
    Source = Table.Combine({Product, Product2}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(Source, {"ID"}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Removed Duplicates",{"ID"},Sales,{"ID"},"Sales",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Sales" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Sales", {"ClientName"}, {"ClientName"}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Expanded Sales",null,"Unsold",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"ClientName"})
in
    #"Replaced Value"
```

Comment: Feel stupid for being stuck on something that at the end was quite easy to do... Thanks a lot really appreciate !

Comment: @Foxan Ng : very impressive screenshots and how to.

Comment: Fantastic step-by-step! I've searched for a solution for hours. Thank you!!

Comment: @GuilhermeHenriqueMendes Glad to help!